# A Panel Control doesn't appear in a GridView Column

Tags: asp.net

one of the GridView Column has to store a Panel Control (with some Controls inside). The problem is, that code doesn't work, I mean, the Panel doesn't appear inside the column.

```
        Panel myPanel = new Panel();
        LinkButton zatw = new LinkButton();
        zatw.CommandName = "Accept";
        zatw.Text = "Accept";

        LinkButton odrz = new LinkButton();
        odrz.CommandName = "Deny";
        odrz.Text = "Deny";

        myPanel.Controls.Add(zatw);
        myPanel.Controls.Add(odrz);

        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT.Columns.Add("Options", typeof(Panel));

        DataRow myRow = DT.NewRow();

        myRow1[0] = myPanel;

        DT.Rows.Add(myRow1);
        GridView1.DataSource = DT;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `DT.Columns.Add("Options", typeof(Panel));` won't accept a control type as the second argument.

From the documentation. DT.Columns is of type

> DataColumnCollection

that, indeed, has a method Add(String, Type) as you used it. But the Type is the column data type... it does not accept a control.

Example:

```
Private Sub AddColumn()
    Dim columns As DataColumnCollection = _
        DataSet1.Tables("Orders").Columns
    Dim column As DataColumn = columns.Add( _
        "Total", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
    column.ReadOnly = True
    column.Unique = False
End Sub
```

In this example, a column of name "Total" and type "decimal" is being created.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell what you are trying to do exactly but I don't think you can create a grid out of controls in this manner.  Why don't have your grid use a template column and then adjust the template based on the data you bind to instead of binding to a prebuilt UI like you are trying to do?